# how can we eliminat features not belonging to the target area before use RANSAC algorithm?

Tags: matlab, feature-selection, ransac

When matching the SIFT feature points, there will
be lots of mismatches. The RANSAC algorithm can be used to
remove the mismatches by finding the transformation matrix
of these feature points. But when the data space contains a lot
of mismatches, finding the right transformation matrix will be
very difficult. What’s more, the probability of finding the error
model is very large. Aiming at solving the problem, I want to use an improved RANSAC algorithm. Before using the
RANSAC algorithm, I want to removed parts of the error feature
points by  eliminating features not
belonging to the target area.for do this I want to calculate the number of every point’s around area containing feature points. When the number less
than the threshold we set, we think the point doesn’t belong
to the target area and remove it.can you help me to do this in matlab?You can see my code below.

```
I = single(rgb2gray(imread('sift_basic_1.jpg'))) ;

[f,d] = vl_sift(I);

I2 = single(rgb2gray(imread('sift_basic_2.jpg'))) ;
[f2,d2] = vl_sift(I2 );
%% SIFT matches
d = im2single(d);
d2 = im2single(d2);
kdtree = vl_kdtreebuild(d ) ;
[index, distance] = vl_kdtreequery(kdtree, d, d2) ;
numMatches = size(index,2)  ;
X1 = f(1:2,index) ; X1(3,:) = 1 ;
X2 =  f2(1:2,:); X2(3,:) = 1 ;
clear H score ok ;
for t = 1:5000
    % estimate homograpyh
    subset = vl_colsubset(1:numMatches, 4) ;
    A = [] ;
    for i = subset
        A = cat(1, A, kron(X1(:,i)', vl_hat(X2(:,i)))) ;

    end
    [U,S,V] = svd(A) ;
    H{t} = reshape(V(:,9),3,3) ;

    % score homography
    X2_ = H{t} * X1 ;
    du = X2_(1,:)./X2_(3,:) - X2(1,:)./X2(3,:) ;
    dv = X2_(2,:)./X2_(3,:) - X2(2,:)./X2(3,:) ;
    ok{t} = (du.*du + dv.*dv) < 6*6 ;
    score(t) = sum(ok{t}) ;
    end
[score, best] = max(score) ;
H = H{best} ;
ok = ok{best} ;
```